# How to create blog app MERN with like instagram blog?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, instagram

I learn `REST api` in Nodejs. I want to create blog app like instagram. Now I create `follow, unfollow` page successfully like instagram. I want to do blog app in like instagram. Is it need `socket.io` ? Can I create this using react hooks? I create blog app but I want this like instagram. When I see blogs and my following friend add blog and I see red point bottom home icon.
Thanks advance!

Comment: If it's necessary to send messages from the server to the app in real time, then one way is to use socket.io, yes. But that's not really necessary for a red dot to appear; your app can simply check for new followers / posts when you navigate to a new page in your app.

Comment: It is I know. I do this. When page change I load blogs. Do you use insta in windows ? I am interest how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to use socket.io? Please check their website docs for that.

Comment: Yes I ask this. I say socket.io or react hooks for use.

Comment: React hooks has nothing to do with pushing messages to a client. Here's the docs: https://socket.io/get-started/

Comment: What exactly you want to know? `socket.io` and React hooks are different part of building apps. First one is for building backend app and second one for frontend app. For asking a question, the question should be clarified.

Comment: It would be nicer for you asking questions while building the app you want one by one.